# Pro Lighting HDRI zip won't install

Tags: add-on

"Pro Lighting Skies Lite"
It allows installation and I am able to check  but refuses to install HDRI zip. Hard for me to spend money on something that seems to be hit or miss when it comes to release updates. Any one help? W1064b.

Comment: https://blendermarket.com/products/pro-lighting-skies/docs
Have you looked at this yet? It works for me

Comment: PS: When you select the HDRI zip file, there's a popup box that appears at your *cursor location* asking for confirmation. If you move your mouse outside of that box, it will disappear and you will have to reselect the zip.